# Integrating scala code coverage tool jacoco into a play 2.2.x project

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, code-coverage

My goal is to integrate jacoco into my play 2.2.0 project.
Different guides on the web I tried to follow mostly added to confusion not to closing in on the goal.

**Adding to confusion**

- Most guides assume the existance of an build.sbt

  - which as it seems as been superseded by an build.scala with a different
- There is a jacoco4sbt and a regular jacoco

  - which one is most appropiate for use with scala play framework 2

**Current state**

in plugins.sbt added

```
addSbtPlugin("de.johoop" % "jacoco4sbt" % "2.1.2")
```

in build.scala added

```
import de.johoop.jacoco4sbt.JacocoPlugin._
lazy val jacoco_settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(jacoco.settings: _*)
```

With these changes i don't get an "jacoco" task in sbt nor in the play console.

What are the appropriate steps to get this working?

**Update**
As requested the content of the build.scala

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager._
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtScalariform._
import play.Project._
import sbt.Keys._
import sbt._
import sbtbuildinfo.Plugin._
import de.johoop.jacoco4sbt.JacocoPlugin._

object BuildSettings {
  val buildOrganization = "XXXXX"
  val buildVersion      = "0.1"
  val buildScalaVersion = "2.10.2"
  val envConfig = "-Dsbt.log.format=false -Dconfig.file=" + Option(System.getProperty("env.config")).getOrElse("local.application")
  scalacOptions ++= Seq("-encoding", "UTF-8", "-deprecation", "-unchecked", "-feature")
  javaOptions += envConfig

  val buildSettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq (
    organization := buildOrganization,
    version      := buildVersion,
    scalaVersion := buildScalaVersion
  )
}

object Resolvers {
  val remoteRepoUrl =  "XXXXXXXXXXXX" at "http://nexus.cXXXXX/content/repositories/snapshots/"
  val publishRepoUrl = "XXXXXXXXXXXX" at "http://nexus.ciXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/content/repositories/snapshots/"
}

object Dependencies {
  val ods =  "XXXXXXXXX" % "XXXXXX-ws" % "2.2.1-SNAPSHOT"
  val scalatest = "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.0.M8" % "test"
  val mockito = "org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "1.9.5" % "test"
}

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  import BuildSettings._
  import Dependencies._
  import Resolvers._

  // Sub-project specific dependencies
  val commonDeps = Seq(
    ods,
    scalatest,
    mockito
  )
  //val bN = settingKey[Int]("current build Number")
  val gitHeadCommitSha = settingKey[String]("current git commit SHA")
  val release = settingKey[Boolean]("Release")

  lazy val jacoco_settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(jacoco.settings: _*)

  lazy val nemo = play.Project(
    "nemo",
    path = file("."),
    settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ buildSettings ++
      Seq(libraryDependencies ++= commonDeps) ++
      Seq(scalariformSettings: _*) ++
      Seq(playScalaSettings: _*) ++
      buildInfoSettings ++
      jacoco_settings ++
      Seq(
        sourceGenerators in Compile <+= buildInfo,
        buildInfoKeys ++= Seq[BuildInfoKey](
          resolvers,
          libraryDependencies in Test,
          buildInfoBuildNumber,
          BuildInfoKey.map(name) { case (k, v) => "project" + k.capitalize -> v.capitalize },
          "envConfig" -> envConfig, // computed at project load time
          BuildInfoKey.action("buildTime") {
            System.currentTimeMillis
          } // re-computed each time at compile
        ),
        buildInfoPackage := "com.springer.nemo"
      ) ++
      Seq(resolvers += remoteRepoUrl) ++
      Seq(mappings in Universal ++= Seq(
        file("ops/rpm/start-server.sh") -> "start-server.sh",
        file("ops/rpm/stop-server.sh") -> "stop-server.sh"
      ))
  ).settings(version <<=  version in ThisBuild)

  lazy val nemoPackaging = Project(
    "nemoPackaging",
    file("nemoPackaging"),
    settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++Seq(Packaging.settings:_*)
  )



  def publishSettings =
    Seq(
      publishTo := Option(publishRepoUrl),
      credentials += Credentials(
        "Repo", "http://mycompany.com/repo", "admin", "admin123"))

}
```

Note: jacoco is running with this but does not pick up our tests. Output:

```
jacoco:cover
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/schl14/work/nemo/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[info] ScalaTest
[info] Run completed in 13 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 0
[info] Suites: completed 0, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 0, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] All tests passed.
[info] Passed: Total 0, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 0
[info] No tests to run for nemo/jacoco:test
```

Comment: Did you set project settings to jacoco_settings. Something like `val core = Project(..., settings = jacoco_settings)`

Comment: As Rin says, just defining jacoco_settings does nothing, you would have to add those to the settings of your play project! You probably don't want to combine them with the Default.defaultSettings either, but instead the play default settings.

Comment: Thanks you two! Got my further as now the command is available. Running jacoco:cover returns "Total number of tests run: 0"

Comment: Do you have a Build.scala or a build.sbt? Can you show us?

Comment: @Schleichardt posted build.scala and jacoco output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it by doing this.

Add the following to plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("de.johoop" % "jacoco4sbt" % "2.1.2")
```

In build.scala i added a new import

```
import de.johoop.jacoco4sbt.JacocoPlugin._
```

and added jacoco to the config section like this

```
lazy val xyz = play.Project(
    "xyz",
    path = file("."),
    settings = Defaults.defaultSettings
      jacoco.settings ++ //this is the important part. 
  ).settings(parallelExecution in jacoco.Config := false) //not mandatory but needed in `most cases as most test can not be run in parallel`
```

After these steps jacoco:cover was available in the sbt and play console and also discovers our tests.

Comment: I am having a hard time integrating sbt-jasmine-plugin settings in play 2.1 you think this can be applied there? https://github.com/barnesjd/sbt-jasmine-plugin the github readme proposes this for Build.scala:

lazy val main = Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies)
  .settings(seq(jasmineSettings : _*))

Comment: @orlybg Iam not shure what you want to do. Please open a separate Question. Iam shure someone will be willing to help!

Answer (score 3):

A better option for Scala code coverage is Scoverage which gives statement line coverage.
https://github.com/scoverage/scalac-scoverage-plugin

Add to project/plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.sksamuel.scoverage" % "sbt-scoverage" % "1.0.1")
```

Then run SBT with

```
sbt clean coverage test
```

Comment: Never heard of it will check it out!

Comment: Seems its starting multiple threads when testing. Something our test setup doesn play nice with. Do you know of an option to disable this?

Comment: That would just be a standard SBT option. Have you disabled parallel tests in SBT? Try parallelExecution in Test := false, or parallelExecution in ScoverageTest := false,

Answer (score 1):

To measure the code coverage of Java code [jacoco4sbt](https://github.com/sbt/jacoco4sbt/wiki) is the best fit.

Add to project/plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("de.johoop" % "jacoco4sbt" % "2.1.2")
```

Add at the end of build.sbt:

```
jacoco.settings
```

Then run in the terminal:

```
//or just the sbt command and then use your browser
sbt jacoco:cover && /usr/bin/x-www-browser target/scala-2.10/jacoco/html/index.html
```

Scala code coverage can also be determined by [SCCT](https://github.com/SCCT/scct).

Add to project/plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.scct" % "sbt-scct" % "0.2.1")
```

Add at the end of build.sbt:

```
ScctPlugin.instrumentSettings
```

And then to see the coverage:

```
sbt scct:test && /usr/bin/x-www-browser target/scala_2.10/coverage-report/index.html
```

Maybe you get the error

> Please either restart the browser with --allow-file-access-from-files
>   or use a different browser.

Maybe you use chrome and the security settings forbid dynamic actions on local files. You can open the page with firefox or use `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` to bind it to the http protokoll and open `http://localhost:8000/target/scala-2.10/coverage-report/` .

Inspiration which generated classes should be excluded from the report can you find on the [mailing list](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?tab=wm#inbox/142230a83e8c4f30).

My test projects are on [GitHub](https://github.com/schleichardt/stackoverflow-answers/tree/so19789638).